# how accurate is microsoft cognitive speaker identification

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to build an application with Microsoft Cognitive Speaker Identification Service. But when I check it using its api some audio are not recognized correctly. I would like to know how much is the accuracy level of the service. Is there any way to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things that can affect the accuracy of the identification e.g. Noise level, microphone quality, echo, etc.

To improve the performance in your condition, you can make sure the enrollment audio is recorded in the same conditions as the test audio (e.g. same microphone) and try to ensure that recording is done in a quiet environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question was related to accuracy level of Microsoft cognitive services. Currently during testing I found out that it is not handsome. It is giving wrong results multiple times in both positive and negative conditions. Now related to environment, I am testing different voices samples recorded in exact same environment. Hardware is also same. Only users are changing.

Answer (score 0):

It does work across multiple users and tried on different PCs/microphones.

I'd make sure that:

- It is in a quiet room/environment
- You are sending the audio correctly... (it is just byte array data, no additional encoding.)
  Also check the header MediaTypeHeaderValue/content type, all request seem to be 'application/json' even though we send wav files.
- Take care when mapping your users to the azure guids, and make sure you are using the correct ones. If you are using the SDK rather than API for profile creation and enrollment, there's no retreival of profile by id at the moment, I have done a workaround, to recreate the profile , and update the id in a database just before Enrollment. (the API doesn't need this though)
- Also make sure you are using the latest API, (urls ending .../speaker/verification/v2.0/ etc... Some of the text independent features in the SDK are  V2 only, and can fail verification becuse V2 stores profiles in 3 separate locations depending on the verification method.
- Also check the profile was created/enrolled using the same verification method you are using to verify.  try with a new profile if unsure.